# Is Cloudinary free tier enough for a small e-commerce website

Tags: node.js, image, multer, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary free plan to make a small website for enterprise, is free tier enough ? since they give me 25 credits per month but idk how to estimate the ,there will be about 500 people access my web page per month, the web sells traveling tour and each tour there will be about like 10 images of places in each tour.

Thanks in advance !

I've been testing a whole week and it toook about 1 credit, but most of them are from uploading since I did upload almost 600 images, but I'm still not sure on larger scale

Answer (score 1):

One credit can be used for:

- 1000 transformations: Most image transformations, including complex chained transformations count as a single transformation.
  Videos, animated images, and some advanced transformations or format optimizations that require sophisiticated processing have special transformation counting rules.
- 1 GB of managed storage: Storage includes both your main asset storage and any revisions backed up to the Cloudinary backup storage.
- 1 GB of delivered bandwidth

For images, the bandwidth is based on the delivered image file size.
For videos, 1 GB generally comes to ~500 seconds of delivered SD video or ~250 seconds of HD video)
Or combined portions of each.

For example, suppose that in one 30-day period, you need:

2 GB of image and video storage (2 credits)
4 GB of delivery bandwidth (4 credits)
4000 transformations (4 credits)
You'll use 10 credits during that period.

So depending on the number of images/videos you have and the size of the images/videos we can get an estimate of how much the bandwidth consumption will be.

You can always start with the Free plan and then upgrade to a higher plan as and when needed.

Comment: Thank you! , so each month I get a whole new 25 GB of credit and have all these benefit ? they're generous XD, I suppose that's enough for a small e-commerce wwebsite since each image is only about 500kb and each guest will load about 10-20 images each time they visit my site

Comment: @Ayakase well, if you used for storage/bandwidth alone than theoretically you have 25GB a month but you need to account for transformation costs as well which gets charged during upload and when you generate derived assets, more here https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_counts#overview